# How to use shinycssloaders withSpinner with a plot output in a bslib card?

Tags: r, bslib, shinycssloaders

I would like to use a spinner with a plotlyoutput and I would also like for that plot to fill the container, but when I use a spinner, the plot does not resize. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out with the documentation on the bslib package https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/reference/as_fill_carrier.html but I'm missing something. Here is an example of the behavior. The plot will resize when there is no spinner. Any ideas?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinycssloaders)
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")

ui <- page_sidebar(
  title = "Penguins dashboard",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    title = "Histogram controls",
    varSelectInput(
      "var", "Select variable",
      dplyr::select_if(penguins, is.numeric)
    ),
    numericInput("bins", "Number of bins", 30)
  ),
  card(max_height = 200,
       full_screen = T,
    card_header("Histogram"),
    plotOutput("p") |> withSpinner()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(penguins) +
      geom_histogram(aes(!!input$var), bins = input$bins) +
      theme_bw(base_size = 20)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: plot is resizing for me

Comment: I tested [here](https://posit.cloud/content/5603136) too but still no resizing. I'm super confused.

Comment: try to update the `bslib` package

Comment: `bslib` is updated to 0.5.1 still no dice

Comment: I'm also noticing this issue.  The card re-sizes to full-screen, but the height of the plotly plot doesn't automatically re-size to fill the expanded card.  It's more obvious if you compare cards with and without the spinner added:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinycssloaders)
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")

ui <- page_sidebar(
  title = "Penguins dashboard",
  sidebar = sidebar(),
  card(full_screen = TRUE,
       plotOutput("p") |> withSpinner()
  ),
  card(full_screen = TRUE,
       plotOutput("p2")
  )
)
```

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in `shinycssloaders`

https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders/issues/76

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that withSpinner() wraps the output in a div. For the plots potential to grow/shrink to fit their container to be activated, the immediate parent needs to be a fillable container.
See https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/filling/index.html

In this case its not quite as simple as piping bslib::as_fill_carrier() onto the output because of the structure that withSpinner returns, but it is possible to target the correct element.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinycssloaders)
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")

ui <- page_sidebar(
  title = "Penguins dashboard",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    title = "Histogram controls",
    varSelectInput(
      "var", "Select variable",
      dplyr::select_if(penguins, is.numeric)
    ),
    numericInput("bins", "Number of bins", 30)
  ),
  card(max_height = 200,
       full_screen = T,
       card_header("Histogram"),
       plotOutput("p") |> withSpinner() |> (\(x) {
         x[[4]] <- x[[4]] |> bslib::as_fill_carrier() 
         x})()
       
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(penguins) +
      geom_histogram(aes(!!input$var), bins = input$bins) +
      theme_bw(base_size = 20)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```